# Create an SSH tunnel with authentication keys - Syntax

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, ssh-keys

I have to create an SSH tunnel to connect a deployment server to an VPN:

`DeploymentServer --> Gateway --> PrivateServer`

Each machine using a key, I tried the following command:

`myMachine $ ssh -i GATEWAY_KEY.pem -N -L 1122:ubuntu@SERVER_PRIVATE_IP:22 ubuntu@GATEWAY_IP`

And then this one in other terminal window:

`myMachine $ ssh -i PRIVATE_SERVER_KEY.pem -p 1122 ubuntu@SERVER_PRIVATE_IP`

But it doesn't work, I get a timeout error. My port 1122 is open and I can SSH it. I don't what I'm doing wrong, is my syntax correct?

It's my first tunnel so don't laugh at me!

---

EDIT 1

I added `-v` and fixed the second SSH call.

---

First call:
`myMachine $ ssh -i GATEWAY_KEY.pem -N -L 1122:ubuntu@SERVER_PRIVATE_IP:22 ubuntu@GATEWAY_IP -v`
Response: `debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).`

Second call:
`myMachine $ ssh -i PRIVATE_SERVER_KEY.pem -p 1122 ubuntu@localhost -v`

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 1122.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file .ssh/wamapi_staging.pem type -1
debug1: identity file .ssh/wamapi_staging.pem-cert type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

And in the first tab again:

```
debug1: Connection to port 1122 forwarding to ubuntu@10.0.5.128 port 22 requested.
debug1: channel 2: new [direct-tcpip]
channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 1122 for ubuntu@10.0.5.128 port             22, connect from ::1 port 60341, nchannels 3
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? ssh to "PrivateServer"? Or establish a VPN somewhere?!

Answer (score 7):

I made it work using the .ssh/config file instead of trying to put all my parameters in my commands. Here is the results if someone needs it:

```
Host the-gateway
  Hostname GATEWAY_IP
  Port 22
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keys/GATEWAY_KEY.pem

Host the-tunnel
  Hostname localhost
  Port 1122
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keys/PRIVATE_SERVER_KEY.pem
```

And then the 2 commands:

```
ssh -N -L 1122:SERVER_PRIVATE_IP:22 the-gateway
ssh the-tunnel
```

Doing that way, SSH can use my pem keys.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, and you want to ssh to "PrivateServer", then your second ssh call should be:

```
myMachine $ ssh -i PRIVATE_SERVER_KEY.pem -p 1122 ubuntu@localhost
```

If not, please clarify in a comment on your question.

Comment: Thanks, I can wait until tomorrow to see if `ubuntu@localhost` works for me.

Comment: Hi @faker, I tried with `ubuntu@localhost` and `localhost` but I have these error messages: `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host` (second ssh call) and `channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed` (first ssh call).

Comment: Are you able to ssh from the gateway to the private server? In any case, try adding `-v` to both ssh calls and edit the output into your question.

Comment: I edited my initial question. I can SSH the private server from the gateway on port 22 without any problem. Maybe should I use another port here also?

Comment: On the gateway, is `AllowTcpForwarding` set to no in `sshd_config`? I'm running out of ideas, it should work like you posted.

Comment: Doesn't help :( I customized the sshd_config as follow: `GatewayPorts yes`, `PermitTunnel yes`, `Port 1122`, `AllowTcpForwarding yes`. But I haven't changed anything on the private server config.

Comment: I have some news! I put `-vvv` to have the maximum level of debug and it's telling me:`debug3: Not a RSA1 key file .ssh/PRIVATE_SERVER_KEY.pem.` 
`debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'`

Comment: see my answer below. I made it work that way. Thanks.